# Getting an error when trying to call LocalReport.Render("EXCELOPENXML")

Tags: c#-4.0, ssrs-2008, nuget-package

I have installed DocumentFormat.OpenXml (ver 2.5.5631.0) from nugetpackage manager in VS2010. I can see the reference to the DLL. I have created a package folder. But when I am trying to execute method:

```
public override void Render(LocalReport report)
{
     this.SetUpParameters(report);

     byte[] renderedReport = report.Render("EXCELOPENXML");
     this.target.UpdateRenderedReportContent(renderedReport);
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: format

When I am using

```
report.Render("EXCEL");
```

I am not getting any error. I have to use EXCELOPENXML to generate xlsx excel.

Comment: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms` are you referencing? If it's less than 11.0, that's probably your problem.

Incidentally, Visual Studio (2013) declined to show me version 11.0 as an option from the Add Reference dialog. I don't understand why. I had to browse to the the assembly in the GAC:

`C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.DLL`

Once you do that, run the following method. You should see EXCELOPENXML as an option now.

```
new LocalReport().ListRenderingExtensions();
```